# Perform Text Sentiment analysis and Keyphrase extraction from excel and store in Azure Blob storage

Tags: python, flask, azure-blob-storage, sentiment-analysis

I want to perform Sentiment analysis and keyphrase extraction on text data stored in an excel format. The sentiments and the extracted keyphrases also need to be appended to the same excel and the final excel needs to be stored in Azure blob storage. Finally this needs be made into a flask app. Would be grateful if anyone can help me on this. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question scope is too wide, so I write a simple demo for you.

Just try the code below to read data from .csv and use Sentiment analysis and then write back to .csv and upload to blob, the only thing you need is to integrate the code with your flask app:

```
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.textanalytics import TextAnalyticsClient
from azure.storage import blob
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
import pandas as pd

region = ''
key = ''

excelFilePath = "<local file path>/test.csv"

storageConnStr = '<storage conn str>'
containerName = '<container name>'
destBlob = 'test-upload.csv'

csv = pd.read_csv(excelFilePath,'rb')
data =csv['text']
documents = data.array

blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(storageConnStr,containerName,destBlob)
credential = AzureKeyCredential(key)
text_analytics_client = TextAnalyticsClient(endpoint="https://"+ region +".api.cognitive.microsoft.com/", credential=credential)

response = text_analytics_client.analyze_sentiment(documents, language="en")

sentiments = [res.sentiment for res in response ]
csv.insert(1, "sentiment", sentiments)
csv.to_csv(excelFilePath, index=False)

blob.upload_blob(open(excelFilePath,'rb').read())
```

Result:

My .csv:

[image]

After running :

[image]

and it has been uploaded to storage :

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much. This is of great help.

Comment: @AnupamBorah， glad to know my post is helpful. Pls click the checkmark beside my answer to accept it :)